# How to fill two different datagrid from one mysql table in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid, ado.net

I have a problem in my application. I'm tying to fill two different `DataGrid`s in C#, using WPF, from one mysql table.

I don't know how to do this properly. Below is my sample code, which does not work.  It currently only fills `czesciTables`, but not `czesciTables2`.

I've been researching how to do this, but google only shows me results from other sources.

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++ )
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id_czesci_symbol AS KOD,
                                                    ilosc AS ILOSC
                                             FROM `test`.`zamowienie`
                                             WHERE z_numer_naprawy='" + numberBox.Content.ToString() + "'
                                             ORDER BY ilosc LIMIT 5;", connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
        czesciTable.DataContext = ds;
    }

    for (int i = 5; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id_czesci_symbol AS KOD,
                                                     ilosc AS ILOSC
                                              FROM `test`.`zamowienie`
                                              WHERE z_numer_naprawy='" + numberBox.Content.ToString() + "'
                                              ORDER BY ilosc LIMIT 5;", connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        adp2.Fill(ds2, "LoadDataBinding");
        czesciTable2.DataContext = ds2;
    }
}
catch (MySqlException ex) 
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally 
{
     connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What exactly should be in these two tables?

Comment: `adp2.Fill(ds2, "LoadDataBinding");` -> Change this to `adp2.Fill(ds2, "LoadDataBinding2");`. It may be because you are using the same name twice.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja I'm selecting data from order table and juts trying to keep 5 elements in one datagrid and other 5 from the same table in second datagrid.

Comment: @MikeEason I changed just like you write and is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, here's the sample code below.

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++ )
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id_czesci_symbol AS KOD,
                                                    ilosc AS ILOSC
                                             FROM `test`.`zamowienie`
                                             WHERE z_numer_naprawy='" + numberBox.Content.ToString() + "'
                                             ORDER BY ilosc LIMIT 5;", connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
        if (i < 5)
            czesciTable.DataContext = ds;
        else
            czesciTable2.DataContext = ds;

        cmd.Dispose();
        adp.Dispose();
    }
}catch (MySqlException ex) {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}finally {
     connection.Close();
}
```

What is is that you are trying to archive? Perhaps we can help you get the better solution to your problem.

Comment: So I'm trying to keep a parts which are used to repair a machine. And in this code i'm selecting them and print to pdf document. I used your sample code and is not working. Maybe it's caused by Limit in sql query?

Comment: Looking at your query, it seems like it queries the same data every time. I don't see the use of `i` that might affect the `resultset`. I suggest you run your queries on DB an make sure that they all return data for all iterations of `i`.

Comment: You are right. The query don't show the data for i. So i don't know how to resolve that problem but I need it :/